# How to git pull in PHP using exec or shell command

Tags: php, laravel, git

The code I tried to pull is

```
shell_exec('git init');
$d = shell_exec('git fetch origin master');
$output = shell_exec('git pull origin master');
```

But it is not working as expected. Sometimes it is working and sometimes it doesn't.

I have two-factor authentication enabled in my git account. Do you think is the reason?

or need to do anything else to pull data?gi

Comment: `But it is not working as expected` what does it do that is not expected and what is actually expected ?

Comment: @NoahBoegli means it is not pulling data.

Answer (score 0):

> I have two-factor authentication enabled in my git account.

Only if you are fetching from a *private* repository.
That would not matter for a public one.

Regarding your code, make sure your current working directory ([`getcwd`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php)) is the folder where your Git repo is.